# React - setting disabled state on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What is the correct way to check if a certain condition is true
or not when trying to set disabled state on a button ?

I have tried the code below, but I get an error.

> Line 237:23:  Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional
> expression  no-unneeded-ternary

```
<Button
variant="contained"
className="global-button"
disableElevation
disabled={!brush_logs_list.length ? true : false}
onClick={applyForEntireMouth}>
APPLY FOR ENTIRE MOUTH
</Button>
```

Comment: The logic is right. The message you are seeing is telling you that `? true : false` is not needed as `!brush_logs_list.length` already evaluates to a boolean with the same mapping as your ternary expression.

Comment: That is not an error, it's just a warning.`disabled={!brush_logs_list.length}` will evaluate itself to a boolean, so no need to explicitly specify boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this;

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  className="global-button"
  disableElevation
  // disabled={!brush_logs_list.length ? true : false}
  disabled={!brush_logs_list.length}  // instead of above line
  onClick={applyForEntireMouth}
>
  APPLY FOR ENTIRE MOUTH
</Button>
```

Actually, the type of `!brush_logs_list.length` is already `boolean`, so you don't need to `? :`  operator. Just using `!brush_logs_list.length` is enough.

Comment: Please explain why your answer works as well as providing the code.

Comment: The type of `!brush_logs_list.length` is already `boolean`, so you don't need to use `? : ` operator.

Comment: Indeed, but please add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bikas Lin is correct. Let me just expand a bit for clarity. The disabled flag only accepts boolean. When using .length to check, 0 (empty) will return false and anything else will return true. The ternary operator is therefore not needed at all because the .length returns exactly what you need.

There are multiple ways to go around this. Say there would be multiple possibilities, for example, if the .length exceeds given amount etc. In that case you want to define a function, for example "handleDisabled" and validate there. switch is a good way/option for these cases (no pun intended).

Comment: you could have edited the answer from bikas lin...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<Button
   variant="contained"
   className="global-button"
   disableElevation
   disabled={(brush_logs_list || []).length}
   onClick={applyForEntireMouth}>
APPLY FOR ENTIRE MOUTH
</Button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).